# failed to read dockerfile: failed to create lease: write /var/lib/docker/buildkit/containerdmeta.db: read-only file system

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to run this project,  https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers but face some issues.

My docker is using `WSL 2`.
[image]

For the resources, it is already `Enable integration with my default WSL distro`

[image]

After cloning the project, when I run `docker-compose build` at src folder, I got this error.

[image]

In Visual Studio, for 'Run containers on project open', I set to `False`. If I set to 'True', it can run automatically and created the container successfully. But, I want to set to 'False', so that I can run it manually.

[image]